# How to overload 'std::string operator()' for hashing?

Tags: c++, string, hash, hashmap

I am implementing a hashmap for a university project, and was wondering if its possible to overload `std::string operator ()` for hashing (using `operator ()` is a design choice).

The hashmap is general and requires the key to have an `operator()`, this is fine for any user-defined types, but is it possible for built-in types?

An explanation would be helpful, but just code will also work (my project choice is already overkill).

I really don't want to reinvent the wheel by re-implimenting my own version of `string`.

PS: I know that hashmaps already exist, and it has a way to hash strings, but using that would defeat the purpose of this project.

Comment: You're not allowed to modify anything inside the `std` namespace. Doing so leads to *undefined behavior*. You could however *specialize* [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), which it already is for `std::string`.

Comment: "and requires the key to have a operator()". Bad decision, revisit.

Comment: That’s one of the reasons why the C++ standard library requires that the key type `Key` in an `std::unordered_map` has a corresponding `hash<key>`.